# Load view component(table) after finish a service call who push an array with info for the table

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, input, angular-services

I'm building a dynamic table to use in my application. I'm using @Input parameters to send info like header and elements for the table.

This is the input for the table component generic.

```
@Input()
public listaElementosTabla: any = [];

@Input()
public titulosCabecera = [];

@Input()
public cantidadMaximaRegistros: number;
```

And I call the table component in the next way:

```
<tabla-component [listaElementosTabla]="arrayElements"
[titulosCabecera]=headElementsArray cantidadMaximaRegistros=5></tabla-component>
```

I have a service to query the information from BD to a specific data and I'm saving that information in the array "arrayElements". I call the service in the onInit page.

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.myService.queryInfoInBd().subscribe(
        (data: ObjectDTO[]) => {
            data.forEach((objectDTO: ObjectDTO) => {
                this.arrayElements.push(objectDTO);
            });
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

The problem here is that the table component is loading first that the call of the service, so, when the component is trying to obtain info about **arrayElements** always is empty.

I know javascript is async, but I don't know how to do to wait until the service finish and the array loads the information and after of that load the table component.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to:

```
<tabla-component *ngIf="arrayElements" [listaElementosTabla]="arrayElements"
[titulosCabecera]=headElementsArray cantidadMaximaRegistros=5></tabla-component>
```

Like that the table component will be called only if the list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to set a "flag" which shows or hides the table element.

Something like this:

in your view (html)

```
<div *ngIf="datosCargados"> 
   <!--Se mostrara el elemento dentro del div si esta bandera es True-->
   <tabla-component [listaElementosTabla]="arrayElements"
   [titulosCabecera]=headElementsArray [cantidadMaximaRegistros]=5></tabla-component>
</div>
```

in your .ts

```
datosCargados: boolean = false; //Por defecto es false para no mostrarse
ngOnInit() {
     this.myService.queryInfoInBd().subscribe(
        (data: ObjectDTO[]) => {
            data.forEach((objectDTO: ObjectDTO) => {
                this.arrayElements.push(objectDTO);
            });
            this.datosCargados = true;
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.datosCargados = false;
        }
    );
}
```

Basically what it will do is, the datosCargos will always be false (will be hidden), until the http subscribes and fetchs the data.

Hope it helps.